# How to fine tune the sound level in iOS just like Mac OS?

Tags: ios, audio

I can fine tune the sound level by <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + volume up/down keys in Mac OS.

Is there any similar way in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When double clicking the home button and swiping **two** times from left to right on **iPhone**, and **one** time on **iPad**, you'll find a *Volume Bar* which will *precisely* let you adjust the volume of the device to the level you want.

[image]